# Material UI grid spacing attribute isn't working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to render some cards using Material UI grids but when I try to add spacing between the cards its not working. I have gone through the documentation and some answers here on stack overflow but still can't fix the issue. I am a beginner and I feel like I am making some silly mistake but I am not able to find the bug.

Here is my code

```
import React from 'react'
import { Grid, makeStyles,Box,Card,CardContent} from '@material-ui/core'


const useStyles =makeStyles(theme=>({
    root:{
      flexGrow:1
    },
  
    heading:{
       fontSize:"clamp(74px,9vw,120px)",
       margin:"6px auto",
       opacity:"0.5",
       color:"#dee3e4",
       textAlign:"center",
       fontFamily:"Poppins,sans-serif"
       
    }, 
}))
function Projects() {
    const { heading,root}=useStyles();
    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className={heading}>Projects</h1>
            <Box m={5}  >
            <Grid container spacing={3} className={root} >  
            
              <Grid sm={12} md={6} lg={3}  >     
                    <Card>
                    <h1>Booksapp</h1>
                    <CardContent>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing eltatis.
                    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing eltatis.
                    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing eltatis.
                    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing eltatis.
                    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing eltatis.
                    </CardContent>
                  </Card>
               </Grid>
                <Grid  sm={12} md={6} lg={3}>
                  <Card>
                    <h1>Booksapp</h1>
                    <CardContent>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing eltatis.
                    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing eltatis.
                    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing eltatis.
                    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing eltatis.
                    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing eltatis.
                    </CardContent>
                  </Card>
                </Grid>
                <Grid  sm={12} md={6} lg={3}>
                  <Card>
                    <h1>Booksapp</h1>
                    <CardContent>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing eltatis.
                    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing eltatis.
                    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing eltatis.
                    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing eltatis.
                    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing eltatis.
                    </CardContent>
                  </Card>
                </Grid>     
            </Grid>
            </Box>
           
        </div>
    )
}

export default Projects
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're not passing the `item` boolean prop to the grid items. The `spacing` prop defines the space between the `item` components and since there are no grid items in the posted code, no spacing gets applied.

```
<Grid container spacing={3} className={root}>
  <Grid item sm={12} md={6} lg={3}>
    <Card>Content</Card>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image: Edit material-ui-grids-gb5y4]

Answer (score 0):

Have to set "item" property to child Grids.

```
<Grid container>
  <Grid item></Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises from the omission of the item boolean prop when passing it to the grid items. The spacing prop is responsible for determining the space between item components. As the provided code lacks additional grid items, the specified spacing of 3 does not take effect.

```
<Grid container spacing={3}>
  <Grid item md={6} lg={3}>
    <Card>Your Card Content here...</Card>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```